# How to fix Error: PDF could not be generated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I'm configing wicked-pdf on my project, and I couldn't make it work, even looking at documentation, older questions.

The project is ruby 2.6.2, rails 6.0.0.rc1, wicked_pdf 1.4, wkhtmltopdf-binary 0.12.3 and docker. These are my codes from controller.rb

```
report = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string('some html here')
```

wicked_pdf.rb

```
WickedPdf.config = {
exe_path: Gem.bin_path('wkhtmltopdf-binary', 'wkhtmltopdf')}
```

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. At the very least you need to include the entire stack trace (if there is one), what precisely "and Docker" means (e.g., your machine config), etc.

Comment: AFAIK the documentation for wicked-pdf is so clear. You can make it work in the first try.
Give it one more try https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf

Comment: Try to follow every step mentioned

Comment: Try to check this if you need any help https://github.com/deepakmahakale/tutorials/tree/master/003-pdf-generation-using-wicked-pdf

Comment: This may not be your issue, but `'some html here'` needs to actually be a well-formed HTML document as a string. Something like `'<!doctype html><html><head><title>test</title></head><body><p>some html here</p></body></html>'`. Also, make sure that `wkhtmltopdf-binary` works with your type of Docker OS. I know there are problems with Alpine Linux containers not having the right system libraries installed for the binary to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using the exact same versions of things you are...

That method is not optimal and will make it harder to trace issues, I suggest trying a different approach:

```
respond_to do |f|
  f.pdf do
    pdf = render_to_string :pdf => "checklist",:encoding => "UTF-8", :layout => 'pdf.html.haml', :template => '/checklists/show.haml'
    send_data(pdf,
              :filename =>  "checklist.pdf",
              :disposition => 'attachment',
              :type => "application/pdf")  
  end
end
```

It works well and allows you to make your pdf templates in a view file making life easier.

Try adding a format code to your show action or a new action you create for it. That will allow Rails to give you more exacting errors at least because you could also view the html in your browser first to confirm the code is error free.